# jQuery to Closure (Keep header on screen)

Tags: google-closure

I'm working on a site that uses Closureextensively. I need to make a header row stick when everything else scrolls.  I know how to do this in jQuery with just a few lines of code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#main_box').scroll(function() {
        $('#header').css({
            'top':$('#main_box').scrollTop()
        });
    });
});
```

But for the life of me I can't figure out or find any documents/tutorials/examples explaining how to do something similar in Closure. How do I go about converting the over into Closure?

Update: Here is in the HTML structure used:

```
<div id="main_box">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean header row?  Is this the header row of a table? Because there is no nice way to do this x-browser (lots of hacks around and some even work).  Also the jquery you are showing does not make the header stick, it just basically disables scrolling on the main_box element.

If you just want an element to stay in a fixed position then you should look at the fixed css layout.

Comment: @gatapia - I've added the html structure used with the code. the header div contains one "row" the content div contains lots of "row"s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get something to stick to the top of the viewport when the page has scrolled past, look into goog.ui.ScrollFloater -> http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_ui_ScrollFloater.html

However for this particular example, you could do...

```
var mainBox = goog.dom.getElement("main_box");
goog.events.listen(mainBox, goog.events.EventType.SCROLL, function(){
    goog.dom.getElement("header").style.top = goog.style.getPageOffsetTop(mainBox); 
}, false, this);
```

I am not sure the getPageOffsetTop is analogous to the scrollTop() method in jQuery, but I'm guessing something in the style library is (possibly goog.style.getClientPosition()) -> http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_style_style.js.html